# How to install last version of qdf on Google Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to install latest version of qpdf. But this script installs version 6.0.0. Latest version is 10.0.1

```
FROM node:12
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y qpdf \
    && apt-get clean
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: That's because the `node:12` Docker image [is based on Debian Stretch](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/a8494b1676216bfe274073993016da0c2e0bfcdd/12/stretch/Dockerfile#L1), a stable version of Debian. It won't include the latest versions of packages. To have the latest version, you could build from source.

Answer (score 0):

According to @jakub's comment, I changed to docker-node version  14  to  14-buster

Now qpdf's version is 8.4.0. It's not 10.0.1 but it's enough for me.
Other qdf versions based on debian is https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=qpdf